# Unable to save changes to context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can someone help please?

I have in my controller the create action:

```
  public class MovieController : Controller
  {
      Connect connection = new Connect();
      Movie movie = new Movie();

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Create(Movie moviecreated)
      {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            connection.Connection().AddObject(moviecreated);
            connection.Connection().Context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(movie);
        }
       }
    }
```

my connection class

```
public class Connect
{
    public ObjectSet<Movie> Connection() 
    { 
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"]; 
        ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext(connStr.ConnectionString); 
        var movieContext = context.CreateObjectSet<Movie>(); 
        return movieContext; 
    } 
 }
```

It is not saving the new addition, what have I got wrong?
Thanks much.

Comment: You have two Movie objects both called movie. 

Which one is it that you are trying to insert into the database?

Comment: oops! I have changed it now but still to no avail. I am trying to save the newly created record

Comment: Does it work now you have changed the name?

Comment: nope it does not save it because it does appear inthe list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public class MovieController : Controller
{
  private Connect connection;
  private Movie movie;

  public MovieController() 
  {
       this.connection = new Connect();
       this.movie = new Movie();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(Movie moviecreated)
  {
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        this.connection.MovieContext.AddObject(moviecreated);
        this.connection.MovieContext.Context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(movie);
    }
   }
}


public class Connect
{
    private ObjectSet<Movie> movieContext;

    public ObjectSet<Movie> MovieContext 
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.movieContext == null) 
            { 
                this.SetMovieContext(); 
            }

            return this.movieContext;
        }
    }

    public void SetMovieContext() 
    { 
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"]; 
        var context = new ObjectContext(connStr.ConnectionString); 
        this.movieContext = context.CreateObjectSet<Movie>(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call connection() it creates another instance.Once you add the new record another , you try to save but different context.
Change it to a property and so save your context.

Comment: how on eart do i do that please?

Comment: you can do it as @andres descales said in the example below.